# Python: Repeat try/except statement until condition met

Tags: python-3.x, try-catch, except, collatz

I'm learning python, and am stuck on a project. The main part of the project was to code the collatz sequence, which wasn't a problem. The next part is to validate the user input using try and except, in order to make sure only an integer value is given in.
So far, I have the following code:

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return number // 2
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        return (3*number) + 1


print('Please enter a number:')
number = ''
try:
    number = int(input())
except ValueError:
    print('Incorrect type of data entered.\nPlease enter an integer!')
    while number is not int:
        try:
            number = int(input())
        except ValueError:
            print('Incorrect type of data entered.\nPlease enter an integer!')

output = number

while output != 1:
    output = collatz(output)
    print(output)
```

My problem is I'm not sure how to repeat the try/except statement until I get an integer from the user. Right now, if I enter a string instead of an integer, the program goes into a loop and entering an integer subsequently does not help. I read quite a few threads on the topic, but they didn't shed light as to the aforementioned problem.

Would really like to understand where I'm going wrong.

Comment: I't fine if you check only 3 times if the given number is an integer. you can check the type with `isinstance` function

Comment: `number is not int` is not ever going to be true. `type(number) is not int` would work, but better to use `not isinstance(number, int)`. Better still: just use `while True: and `break` out when no exception is raised.

Comment: You're of course right. That was a very silly mistake on my part, I missed out on the type().
I'll check out is instance(number, int) - I'm not aware of the function. But thanks a lot for the tips!! Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
valid=False
while not valid:
    try:
        number=int(input())
        valid=True
    except ValueError:
        print('Incorrect type of data entered.\nPlease enter an integer!')
```

Comment: `while True`, and `break`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `isinstance(x, int)`, where x is input.

It returns True if x is an int. Just another solution, in case you were looking for a different way!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll check out the isinstance function - I wasn't aware of it until now. Thanks for the tip!!